# Configure firewall (Shorewall/UFW) to allow traffic for services on an Ubuntu Server

Tags: configuration, ssh, samba, firewall

I have an Ubuntu Server 11.04 x64 which I want to secure.

The server will be open to Internet and I want to be able to SSH/SFTP into the machine and the SSH-server runs on a custom set port. I also want a web server accessible from the Internet. These tasks seems not to hard to perform but I also want SAMBA-shares to be accessible from within the local network and this seems to be a bit trickier.

If possible I also want to be able to "stealth" the ports necessary to protect the server further but also allow the SAMBA-shares to be automatically found within the local network.

I've never configured firewalls before except for a router and I always bump into a bunch of problem when doing it all by myself so I was hoping for some tips or preferably a guide on how to this.

Thank you!

**Update:**

On second thought I'd could just as likely go with UFW if the same settings are achievable ("stealth" ports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned everything I needed to configure [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) from [this excellent tutorial](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:r8Y3wnPumw8J:blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/firewall-ubuntu-servers/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ar):

Enable ssh (replace 22 with the non-default port)

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Enable ufw and by default deny all incoming (udp/tcp) traffic:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo default deny
```

Enable Samba

```
sudo ufw allow samba
```